# Extract lines from paragraph in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Firstly, the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Rzz2n/).

It's a part of my project, and the content is too much in HTML, so I only show the structure:

```
<div class="line">
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <font face="Arial">
                    <p>
                        <!--content-->
                        <br>
                        <!--content-->
                        <br>
                        <!--content-->
                        <br>
                        <!--content-->
                    </p>
                </font> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

This part is the content I should handle. What I should do is to split this table into multiple ones according to `<br>`, and keep the original styles. That is, each paragraph should be independent in indifferent tables.

The code below shows my previous solution to those which had originally split the content with `<p>`. So you should have already know my intention.

```
function split_func($div) {
    var $rows = $div.find("table tr td p");  // fail to detect tr in this demo
    n = $rows.length;  
    $rows.each(function(i) {            
        var $clone = $div.clone(true, true).insertAfter($div);
        $clone.find("table tr td p").each(function(j) {
            if(i !== (n-j-1)) $(this).remove();
        });
    });
    $div.remove(); 
}
```

The line with comment is where I should organize the extraction function. Could you please tell me how to solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will let you split every paragraph into its own table:

```
$('.line p').each(function(){
    var paragraphs = $(this).html().split('<br>');
    for(var i=0;i<paragraphs.length;i++){
        if(paragraphs[i]!= '') {       
             $(this).closest('table').clone().appendTo($(this).closest('.line')).find('p').html(paragraphs[i]);
        }                         
    }
});
$('.line table:first').remove();
```

**[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Rzz2n/5/)**

Comment: Thank you, this is very effective. Could you please how to make modification on my function? I append `html().split('<br>');` in my comment place and become `var rows = div.html().split('<br>');` but error says ` Object [object Array] has no method 'each' `

Comment: May I ask why do you need to update your function when the solution I provided will work out of the box?  You don't really need to have a separate loop call the function. I would say just use the code I provided, but [here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rzz2n/9/) in case you decide to go your way

Answer (score 0):

The above code example fails to specify a tbody element in the hierarchy of elements you're trying to find:

Also, I wouldn't recommend prefixing variables with the $ sign as this should be considered a reserved character when using the jQuery library.

```
var line_w = $(".line");      
for(var i = 0 ;i<line_w.length;i++){         
    if(line_w[i].getElementsByTagName('p').length){
        $(line_w[i]).each(function(i, div) {
            split_func($(div));
        });
    }
}


function split_func(div) {
    var rows = div.find("table tbody tr td p");  // fail to detect tr in this demo
    n = rows.length;
    rows.each(function(i) {            
        var clone = div.clone(true, true).insertAfter(div);
        clone.find("table tbody tr td p").each(function(j) {
            if(i !== (n-j-1)) $(this).remove();
        });
    });
    div.remove(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Since I have multiple tables to handle, some of these tables don't include `<tbody>`. Nevertheless, it still works. In this table <p> contains all the content instead of each paragraph, so I don't know how to split according to `<br>`.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this? Easy way, DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/Rzz2n/8/

```
var output = $('.line p.Default').html();
output = output.replace(/\<br><br>/g, '</p></font></td></tr></tbody></table><table><tbody><tr><td><font face="Arial"><p>');
$('.line').html('<table><tbody><tr><td><font face="Arial"><p>'+output);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But the original html code is the input of my project, and the styles of tables and tr td should be kept when extracting.